# Using .NetTopologySuite to convert a GeoJson Multipolygon to a single Polygon

Tags: c#, nettopologysuite

We have a GeoJson Multipolyogn((( etc. etc.

We need to convert this to a single polygon. 
We have looked at the .NetTopologySuite but cannot figure out if this is possible.

It seems if you already have several polygons you can use union to create a single polygon.

But how do you create a single polygon from a GeoJson Multipolygon.

Any assistance would be appreciated.